# Input field returns tags that have textContents of each single character of a string

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, split

I'm trying to achieve that website feature where every item you enter is converted into tags and each one is separated by a character (such as comma or space). What I want is, on `keyup`, a `span` should be appended to the `.tags` containing with the `textContent` of the entered item; its `textContent` should live-update as the user enters the name of the item. The result I got instead was a `span` for every single character; in short, "one character, one tag", and when a comma is present, it inserts a blank tag.

```js
var query = document.querySelector.bind(document);

query('#textfield').addEventListener('keyup', insertTag);

function insertTag(e) {
  var evt = e.target;

  if(evt.value) {

    var items = evt.value.split(',');

    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      var span = document.createElement('span');
      span.textContent = items[i];
      evt.nextElementSibling.appendChild(span);
    }
  
  }
}
```

```css
section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: firebrick;
  position: relative;
}

section .container {
  max-width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

section #textfield {
  width: 512px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  background: transparent;
  color: #eee;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: .3rem;
}

section #textfield::placeholder {
  font: 0.8rem 'Arial', sans-serif;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
}

section .tags {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 33% 33% 33%;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

section .tags > span {
  background: maroon;
  color: #ddd;
  text-align: center;
  font: 1rem 'Arial', sans-serif;
  padding: 0.7rem 1rem;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

section .tags > span:after {
  content: 'Remove';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2.5;
  border-radius: inherit;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  display: none;
}

section .tags > span:hover {
  font-size: 0;
}

section .tags > span:hover:after {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <input id="textfield" type="text" name="tag" placeholder="Enter an item and press Enter to add to list">
    <div class="tags"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I hope someone would help me fix this.

PS. Excuse my noobness.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/vppo65tw/ like this? It's not clear what you need.

Comment: In @wostex snippet you will always just have one tag.

I guess you just forgot to reset the existing tags as you are creating tags for the whole value of the input. Furthermore you should check if the tag to insert contains any characters and is not empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't reset your existing tags before creating new tags for the complete input value.

```js
var query = document.querySelector.bind(document);

query('#textfield').addEventListener('keyup', insertTag);

function insertTag(e) {
  var evt = e.target;

  if(evt.value) {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tags");
    x[0].innerHTML=""; // resetting content
    var items = evt.value.split(',');
    
    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      var span = document.createElement('span');
      if(items[i].length > 0) { //don't add empty tags
        span.textContent = items[i];
        evt.nextElementSibling.appendChild(span);
      }
    }
  
  }
}
```

```css
section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: firebrick;
  position: relative;
}

section .container {
  max-width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

section #textfield {
  width: 512px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  background: transparent;
  color: #eee;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: .3rem;
}

section #textfield::placeholder {
  font: 0.8rem 'Arial', sans-serif;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
}

section .tags {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 33% 33% 33%;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

section .tags > span {
  background: maroon;
  color: #ddd;
  text-align: center;
  font: 1rem 'Arial', sans-serif;
  padding: 0.7rem 1rem;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

section .tags > span:after {
  content: 'Remove';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2.5;
  border-radius: inherit;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  display: none;
}

section .tags > span:hover {
  font-size: 0;
}

section .tags > span:hover:after {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <input id="textfield" type="text" name="tag" placeholder="Enter an item and press Enter to add to list">
    <div class="tags"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Great tip. Just one question, why empty the contents of `.tags` when it's already empty?

Comment: It's only empty before adding the first tag. When calling insertTag() for the 2nd time, there is already one tag in the .tags container. Try debugging in browser to see step by step what's happening. You can add a check to only empty the content when it is not empty, but it is not a performance issue to do it everytime. So I kept it the lazy way. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot, bro :)